# Graphql Yoga Express - no overload matches this call

Tags: express, graphql, mesh

```
import { createServer } from '@graphql-yoga/node';
import express from 'express';

// create mesh
const { schema, getEnveloped } = await getBuiltMesh();

// create express server
const app = express();

// create yoga server
const server = createServer({
    schema: schema,
});

// add graphql endpoint
app.use('/graphql', server);
```

> No overload matches this call.   The last overload gave the following
> error.
> Argument of type 'YogaNodeServerInstance<{ req: IncomingMessage; res: ServerResponse; }, { req: IncomingMessage; }, {}>' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'Application'.
> Type 'YogaNodeServer<{ req: IncomingMessage; res: ServerResponse; }, { req: IncomingMessage; }, {}> & ((req:
> IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse) => Promise<...>)' is missing the
> following properties from type 'Application': init,
> defaultConfiguration, engine, set, and 60 more.ts(2769)

According to https://www.graphql-yoga.com/docs/integrations/integration-with-express it should work.

Please help me understand my problem with Grapqhl Yoga and express.

All i want is expose my yoga server.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue, it's because I am extending `@tsconfig/node-lts-strictest` which has `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` turned on.

Either turning off the flag in `tsconfig.json` or using a `// @ts-expect-error` (which was my preferred way as I want my config to stay strict) seems to be the only viable option at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with you. I think it is resolved in the latest version of `@graphql-yoga/node` (2.13.13 for me).

You can update the package version to latest by:

> yarn upgrade @graphql-yoga/node --latest

or

> npm i @graphql-yoga/node@latest

if you are using npm